# Automatically compile any Java class when the file is dropped in a directory

Tags: macos, automation, compilation, filesystemwatcher

I look at a lot of small Java programs. It would be convenient if I could set up a directory (or directory structure) on my Mac where any time I add a .java file, javac automatically runs and attempts to compile that file. I've briefly looked into Automator actions, but found nothing that fits the bill. Then I got to thinking: on my PC, I would use the .Net FileSystemWatcher class and write the code myself. But before I try that on my Mac with Mono, I want to ask the community for other ideas. Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JDK6 you can programmatically compile, so you could write your own program to do this, which may be slightly better than doing it in mono.

So you would just have a program that is always running, it looks for either any new files or a file that has been changed since the last check and then just compiles them, and you may want it to pass information to a dashboard window when there are errors, and perhaps some status info so you know it is working.

http://binkley.blogspot.com/2005/09/programmatically-compiling-java-in-jdk.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the .java files available at the start, you could write a shell script to compile them all in one run -- in different directories if you need to.

If you explained why you would want this, maybe I/we could be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As for why: I'm teaching an introductory programming course, so I look at a lot of small Java programs.  It's not a killer to work on the command line, but I got to thinking about how to streamline things.

Comment: Having taught introductary programming courses myself, I guessed as much. The command line *is* great for streamlining things, if you ask me.